# how to read API data and insert it into MYSQL with php

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to get conversion rates from an API and I get the following data:

https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2017-01-01&end_at=2018-09-01&symbols=EUR&base=GBP

How can I loop over the data and insert date & conversion rate into MYSQL DB.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I am currently standing here:

```
$host="localhost";
$user="conversion";
$pass="password";
$db="areporting";
$connect= new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die("ERROR:could not connect 
to the database!!!");


$string = file_get_contents("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2017-01-01&end_at=2018-09-01&symbols=EUR&base=GBP");
$json = json_decode($string, true);


var_dump($json);
```

here a screenshot of the Data I get: 
[image]

Comment: `json_decode()` would help.

Comment: you can do it by decoding the data into an array, looping over the array and then constructing an INSERT statement with a clause for each row of the array, and then executing that statement. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Im unsure how to loop this data I get... normaly I would do it with a forach loop, but I cant seem to loop it correctly

Comment: what problem happens, exactly? Did you decode the JSON into an array first? What does the JSON even look like?

Comment: just added a screenshot

Comment: data is text, so text would be better.

Answer (score 4):

You can use foreach on json result :

```
  <?php
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "username";
        $password = "password";
        $dbname = "myDB";

        // Create connection
        $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
        // Check connection
        if ($conn->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
        } 
        $string = file_get_contents("https://api.exchangeratesapi.io/history?start_at=2017-01-01&end_at=2018-09-01&symbols=EUR&base=GBP");
        $json = json_decode($string, true);


        foreach($json['rates'] as $date =>$conversion){
            $sql = "INSERT INTO Mytable (id, date, conversion)
                    VALUES ( '$date', ".$conversion['EUR'].")";

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "New record created successfully"."<br>";
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."<br>";
            }

        }
        $conn->close();
        ?>
```

Comment: the foreach loop you posted doesnt work. I get the logic, but the Data I am not managing to loop through

Comment: try now i updated my code i was having mistake on $date->EUR now it became conversion->EUR

Comment: 1. this could be done by constructing a single INSERT statement containing multiple clauses (one for each row required to insert), which would be a lot faster on the SQL side than running INSERT dozens of times.  2. Using parameterised queries would be much better solution (for avoiding syntax errors and also SQL injection attacks - we should not be trusting data coming from a remote source, even if we think we know what will be in it, we can't guarantee it won't ever be compromised)

Comment: @ADyson you mean to save it in an array and then implode the data into one query?

Comment: I still get nothing showing up. no error message and no success. I tried the loop you suggested, it doesnt work ( tried outputing a var dump on each loop, didnt output anything)

Comment: @HamzaNig when I var dump $json-> rates I get NULL. Thats one of my main issues ...

Comment: $json['rates'] on the other hand outputs some data. I just dont know how to loop through the Array on $json['rates].

Comment: @Michael uh sorry i forget that was an array yeah you need to change -> with []  i update my code check it

Comment: @Michael "I just don;'t know how to loop through the Array on $json['rates']"... you loop by using `foreach($json['rates'] as $date =>$conversion){` exactly as per this answer. This syntax even nicely gives you the key ($date) and the value ($conversion) for each entry in the array. I suggest you study the PHP loop syntax in the manual if you're not sure how to make a loop...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the Tips, here I have my working solution:

```
foreach($json['rates'] as $date => $conversion){

$timestamp = strtotime($date);
$sql = "INSERT INTO m_fx_rate_temp
(`base`, `counter`, `fxRate`, `date`) VALUES ('gbp', 'eur', ".$conversion['EUR'].", Date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME($timestamp), '%Y-%m-%d'))";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully"."<br>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."<br>";
}

}
```